# Как пользоваться Fake Store API?

Tags: javascript, html, css, json

Дали задачу сделать карточки товара с помощью сервиса Fake Store API, я новичок в этой сфере. Прочитав документацию ничего не понял, как подключать к html, и впринципе как добавить карточки товара, буду благодарен если кто-то объяснит, скрин что надо сделать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: К html подключать через тег `<script></script>`. И там вставлять `fetch...`, который в документации пишет. И в последнем `.then(json => ...` - `json` вставлять в HTML элемент

Comment: @entithat понял как подключить спасибо большое, когда подключил надо создать json файл и там написать карточки товары сколько надо и потом как то это закинуть в html? извини что вас напрягаю просто я вообще в этом не разбираюсь)

Comment: Нет, когда вы пишите `fetch(...)`, то вам с чужого сервера возвращается уже карточка продукта. Этот продукт будет записан в переменную `json` (как в доке писало). И с этой переменной вам уже надо работать. Никаких файлов там не надо дополнительных

Comment: @entithat если вам не трудно можете показать пример как добавить карточку товара и например стилизовать ее, я пытаюсь но безуспешно, не судите строго я новичек(

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-mountain-u25tr

Comment: @entithat спасибо большое, без вас бы я точно не справился)

Comment: пожалуйста.....

Comment: @entithat Добрый день, прошу прощения но вчера так и не смог понять как разобраться с моей задачей, сможете помочь ее сделать, мне надо засунуть с этого сервиса 8 карточек товара, я пытался но ничего не отображается(

Comment: куда засунуть.?

Comment: @entithat могу ли я вам кинуть ссылку на гитхаб где мой проект и укажу блок куда нужно поставить?